# Convert div to img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to overlay a smaller image on a bigger one. I would like to do 
    img src=[overlayed images]

```
<!-- canvas.html -->
<script>
function renderContent() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("content"), {
        allowTaint: true       
    }).then(function(canvas) {
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(canvas);
    });
  }
</script>

<body onload="renderContent()">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js">
</script>

<div id="content" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
<img style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;" src="http://myownradar.alerteagle.com/comp/800x500/north_carolina.gif"> 
<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 190px;" src="http://radarchive.neocities.org/legend.png"></div>

<br> <div id="result"></div>
```

[Result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcY8j.png)

The html2canvas function does not generate an image with a URL. 
 What way could I instantaneously combine images on the web?

New Code

```
<style>
.multi_bg_example {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://myownradar.alerteagle.com/comp/800x500/north_carolina.gif), url(http://radarchive.neocities.org/legend.png), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right, left, right;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), -webkit-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), -ms-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
</style>

<div class="multi_bg_example"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "combine"? Blend mode? Overlay?

Comment: I would like to view the generated image as a .gif file.

Comment: Overlay the images

Comment: get the `src` attribute from each and set the `background-image` style appropriately

Comment: just saying but my method was setting the div's `backround-image` and inside the div i use `img` that how i overlay 2 images. if that helps.

Comment: @ooo-Ghost-ooo I added my new code for the background image.

Comment: It still does't let me see the URL.